# Get all automatically generated values after insert

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, mysql-connector

After inserting a new row into a database table it is possible to get the value of the generated primary key like this:

```java
PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(query, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
ResultSet keys = statement.getGeneratedKeys();
```

But how can I retrieve other automatically generated values that are not keys. Lets say my table definition looks like this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE foo (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    changed TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);
```

Is it possible to get the value of the column `changed` without the need to query the database again with the returned primary key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no, data change statements INSERT, UPDATE do not return values of the fields changed/inserted. You can ask for the last key but even that is an additional DBMS call.

Comment: In that case is it recommended to create a stored procedure which does the insert and returns all the needed values and call it from the datalayer?

Comment: In general, I don't think it is a good practice because a stored procedure will never give you the flexibility of INSERT and SELECT. It means a the code you need to maintain becomes twice the size. Also, access layers might not all deal correctly with a SP that returns results. On specific cases, sure, it's not wrong per se. I would only advise you to think carefully if you really need it.